# "RewriteEngine On" in virtual host not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

This is my virtual host entry.

Version: Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName web1.net
    ServerAlias www.web1.net

    ServerAdmin webmaster@web1.net

    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/web1.net_error_log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/web1.net_access_log combined

    DocumentRoot /web/web1.net/htdocs

    <Directory "/web/web1.net/htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        AllowOverride All

        RewriteEngine On    #This is not working
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on   # It works.
#abc5
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com
```

When I put the same (RewriteEngine on) in .htaccess file it starts working, why I need require to put this in .htaccess when it is present in virtual host.

Do I need any other changes in Apache config?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `RewriteEngine on` in each directory's .htaccess if you want to enable rewriting. So in short:

- `RewriteEngine on` from server config doesn't come into effect for `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`
- `RewriteEngine on` in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` doesn't come into effect for any `/subdir/.htaccess`

Comment: I had done this setup previously, it was working properly. I'm deploying the same application with same configuration.